# mysql LEFT join query optimize

Tags: mysql

i have query

```
SELECT  P.*, COUNT(L.to) AS likes, U.name AS ownerName, U.username AS ownerUsername,
    U.picture AS ownerPicture
FROM sn_posts P LEFT JOIN sn_users AS U
    ON U.id = P.ownerID
LEFT JOIN sn_likes AS L
    ON L.to = P.id
WHERE (P.ownerID = 69)
GROUP BY P.id
ORDER BY P.id DESC
```

it's taking  - 0.3337 sec time,

Comment: i want optimize my above query..

Comment: hello, and welcome to SO - please try to provide more information - table structures, amount of data, indizes and so on - so people actually have a way to help you.

Comment: You can add indices to the join columns, other than this your query looks OK to me.

Comment: please provide your table data with desired result.That will be easy to understand

Comment: Can you have posts without a matching user? If not then change the first left join to an INNER JOIN. Do you have an index on the _to_ field on the _sn_likes_ table?

Comment: if i use INNER JOIN than result " 11 total, Query took 0.7039 sec "

Comment: Please post the table declares and an EXPLAIN of the query.. This way we may be able to help you, but without them there is virtually nothing more we can say that might be useful. Note a direct time on its own is not that meaningful as other factors apply (for a start if you should use SQL_NO_CACHE to avoid the timings being massively influenced by cached queries).

Answer (score 0):

Add an index for table `sn_posts` with `ownerID` field may 
be nicer

Comment: already index on ownerID but result is Showing rows 0 - 10 ( 11 total, Query took 0.3854 sec)

Comment: try this one:SELECT  P.*, COUNT(L.to) AS likes, U.name AS ownerName, U.username AS ownerUsername,
    U.picture AS ownerPicture
FROM sn_posts P LEFT JOIN sn_users AS U
    ON U.id = P.ownerID AND P.ownerID = 69
LEFT JOIN sn_likes AS L
    ON L.to = P.id
GROUP BY P.id
ORDER BY P.id DESC